# Handling Calendars in Appium

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

[image]
I am using Appium and JAVA to automate a native Android App. I have written the test cases and they are working fine. I am stuck on a case in which I have to select a date from a calendar that pops when clicked on a field. I have to select year first, then month and then date. Can anybody help with the code?

The above screenshot shows the calendar that pops up. I have used X-paths and Index to automate this but that did not work (it doesn't recognize the X-paths)

Comment: Nauman will you share the code that you are using to select and the png of that so we can understand better

Comment: @akshaypatil Screenshot added.

Comment: can you check if the calender pop-up elements has any unique id/automation id using **appium desktop inspector** or **uiautomatorviewer**?

Comment: @SubanDhyako No unique id on this. I checked via uiautomatoeviewer.

Comment: If there is no unique id shown in uiautomatorviewer you can use appium destop inspector to check exact xpath.